# Generic class which compares two objects with same type and getting the smallest of both?

Tags: java, object, generics, compare

I try to write a generic class which compares two object with the same type. The class shall get me the smallest of both. My code doesn't work.

```
public class compare < T > {

    private T type1;
    private T type2;

    public compare(T type1, T type2) {
        this.type1 = type1;
        this.type2 = type2;
    }

    public T getSmallest() {
        if (type1 > type2) {
            return type2;
        } else if (type1 == type2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return type1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty off, so no it won't work. Like `getSmallest()` returns `0` or `T`. You can't just return different types like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
Please read and follow the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: You need to make sure `T extends Comparable<? super T>` and call `type1.compareTo(type2)`.

Comment: You cannot *compare* objects using operators like `>` and `==`. there is an interface to define the *natural order* of Objects  which is `Comparable` Let your Objects implement this interface and use it `compareTo()` method to find the smaller one. No generics is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue with your code is that the comparison operators `<` and `>` are defined ONLY for primitive arithmetic types (char, byte, short, int, long, float and double).  You cannot apply those operators to arbitrary reference (non-primitive) types, and generic type parameters MUST be reference types.

It appears you are trying to re-invent the `Comparator` and `Comparable` interfaces. Reference types can be "compared" for *ordering* (i.e. larger/smaller) only if they implement the `Comparable<T>` interface and provide a `compareTo()` method, or using a helper class that implements `Comparator<T>`.  In the first case (`implements Comparable<T>`) the class itself defines the comparison in whatever terms are appropriate based on its internal state; in the second case the comparison is specified in the helper `implements Comparator<T>` class, based on whatever internal state is visible to the helper.

Take a look at the [Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) section of the Oracle Java tutorials for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on above comments, you should implement Comparable for any class T that you want to be able to compare/sort with other objects of type T. The interface has only one method you must implement, the `compareTo` function which should return a negative, positive, or zero value. You can then use this function in your generic class for T when it implements Comparable.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score -1):

You should implement the Comparable but also the getSmallest should become the compareTo(T o) method.

Check the javadoc for the interaface here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html